# I want to read the values for the pixels from a text file and then create an image file with the defined pixels.

Tags: c#, image, file-io, bitmap, text-files

I'm new to c#, and I need to read the values for the pixels from a text file and then create an image file with the defined pixels. I found this code, but not sure how to use it:(

Please help!
I don't have to draw anything on the screen, but in a jpg/bmp/png... file.

```
private void SetPixel_Example(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create a Bitmap object from a file.
    Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap("Grapes.jpg");

    // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmap.Width,
        myBitmap.Height);

    // Set each pixel in myBitmap to black. 
    for (int Xcount = 0; Xcount < myBitmap.Width; Xcount++)
    {
        for (int Ycount = 0; Ycount < myBitmap.Height; Ycount++)
        {
            myBitmap.SetPixel(Xcount, Ycount, Color.Black);
        }
    }

    // Draw myBitmap to the screen again.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, myBitmap.Width, 0,
    myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
}
```

Comment: you will have to define text file format to store image first, then search of how to parse text file, then create blank `Bitmap` of needed size, `SetPixel`'s and finally [BitmapSave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.save.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only thing missing is `Bitmap.Save`, which saves the result to a file. Details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).

```
myBitmap.Save(@"C:\example.png");
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work the way I did it, but I'm sure you are right, so I'll keep on trying!